# How to add SweetAlert2 in If statement?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a simple alert that will alert if you leave it blank and hit the enter key on to-do list by using SweetAlert2 with JavaScript.

I've added some codes that was on document but it's not working.
I'm not sure how to code it in if statement.

Any help is appreciated!

Here's what I did.
I followed the usage on https://sweetalert2.github.io/

So I installed,

```
npm install sweetalert2
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>to-do App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <form id="new-task-form">
        <input
          type="text"
          id="new-task-input"
          placeholder="What's your plans?"
        />
        <input type="submit" id="new-task-submit" value="ADD" />
      </form>
    </header>

    <main>
      <section class="task-list">
        <h2>Tasks</h2>

        <div id="tasks"></div>
      </section>
    </main>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const form = document.querySelector("#new-task-form");
  const input = document.querySelector("#new-task-input");
  const list_el = document.querySelector("#tasks");

  form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const task = input.value;
    const Swal = require('sweetalert2')   // Added this!

    if (!task) {
      Swal.fire("Whoop! Forgot to add something?");   // Added this!
      return;
    }

    const task_el = document.createElement("div");
    task_el.classList.add("task");

    const task_content_el = document.createElement("div");
    task_content_el.classList.add("content");

    task_el.appendChild(task_content_el);

    const task_input_el = document.createElement("input");
    task_input_el.classList.add("text");

    task_input_el.type = "text";

    task_input_el.value = task;
    task_input_el.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");

    task_content_el.appendChild(task_input_el);

    const task_actions_el = document.createElement("div");
    task_actions_el.classList.add("actions");

    const task_edit_el = document.createElement("button");
    task_edit_el.classList.add("edit");

    const task_delete_el = document.createElement("button");
    task_delete_el.classList.add("delete");
    task_delete_el.innerHTML = "Delete";

    task_actions_el.appendChild(task_edit_el);
    task_actions_el.appendChild(task_delete_el);

    task_el.appendChild(task_actions_el);

    list_el.appendChild(task_el);

    input.value = "";

    task_edit_el.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (task_edit_el.innerText.toLowerCase() === "edit") {
        task_input_el.removeAttribute("readonly");
        task_input_el.focus();
        task_edit_el.innerText = "Save";
      } else {
        task_input_el.setAttribute("readonly", "readyonly");
        task_edit_el.innerText = "Edit";
      }
    });

    task_delete_el.addEventListener("click", () => {
      list_el.removeChild(task_el);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: That page has examples with `if` statements: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#input-types. But `require` is unlikely to work on a browser unless you're using webpack or Require.js (note that it says "CommonJS" in a comment above that line). I don't see a reference to the script in your HTML, as it shows in https://sweetalert2.github.io/#usage...

Comment: Thanks, solved it. Just had to remove "const Swal = require('sweetalert2')" part.

Answer (score 0):

Just import sweetalert by <script>

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>to-do App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    ............
    <script src="node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"> </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've done that but it didn't work : /

Comment: O it worked! Just had to delete "const Swal = require('sweetalert2')". Thank you!